# Bind Checkbox of gridview with integer datafield of database

Tags: asp.net, gridview

I need to bind the Checkbox within the gridview with Integer datafield of database.

Actually, when the field value is 1 the checkbox should be checked itself and when 2 it should be unchecked itself.

Code i have tried is as follows but they are not working properly.

```
<asp:CheckBox ID="chkstatus" runat="server" Checked='<%# 
Bind("status") %>'

<asp:CheckBox ID="chkstatus" 
runat="server" Checked='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "status") %>'
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You bind like...

```
<asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox1" runat="server" 
     Checked='<%# Eval("status").ToString() == "1" ? true : false) %>' />
```

Comment: <asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox1" runat="server" 
     Checked='<%# Eval("status").ToString() == "1" ? true : false %>' />